# myFile.write(item+"\n") TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, list, file, int, sum

Getting error:

> myFile.write(item+"\n") TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +:
>   'int' and 'str'

and not sure why. Where shall I add the `int`? This is my code

```
#comment program to create a list in a file
numberList = []
for counter in range (1,7):
    number = int(input("choose a number")) #asks user to enter 6 numbers
    numberList.append(number) #stores the numbers in a list

#writes numbers to a file
myFile = open('numbers.txt','w')
for item in numberList:
    myFile.write(item+"\n")

myFile = open('numbers.txt','rt')
contents = myFile.read()
print(contents)
numSum = sum(numberList)
print(numSum)
sumTimesSum = sum * sum
average = SumTimesSum / 6
print(average)

myFile.close()
```

Comment: Elements in `numberList` are integer    `number = int(input("choose a number"))` then `numberList.append(number)`  To fix it use     `myFile.write(str(item)+"\n")` or     `myFile.write('{item}\n'.format(item=item))`

Comment: myFile.write( str(item) + "\n") should fix it

Answer (score 1):

`numberList` is a list of `int` and when you write to a text file, you must convert it to `string`, so:

```
for item in numberList:
    myFile.write(str(item)+"\n")
```

Or without using `for` loop

```
s = '\n'.join(map(str, numberList))
myFile.write(s)
```

Comment: @milahstott .. Do accept the answer that fits you the best if you are satisfied with any of them to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's literally trying to *add* the string and the number (i.e. `1 + 2 = 3`, `"abc" + 1 = ???`). You need to convert the number to a string.

```
myFile.write(str(item) + "\n")
```

You could also use string formatting.

```
myFile.write("%d\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to make `item` a string.

```
myFile.write(+str(item)+"\n")
```